# Python VK API. Как найти адрес страницы по id пользователя?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Как через VK API получить адрес страницы пользователя, который он сам выбрал, зная его id?
UPD Имеется ввиду адрес вида vk.com/dimka777

Comment: адрес страницы по ид? 'vk.com/' + id

Comment: Я говорю про адресс который пользователь сам себе выбирает, по типу vk.com/dimka777

Comment: Для этого есть метод `users.get` в поле fields укажите screen_name и он вернет вам короткое имя.

Comment: HedgeHog, спасибо, работает.